# Emacs Python error delay

Tags: python, emacs

I'm using Python 3.3 and Emacs 23.4 on Windows 7.  I'm getting some odd behaviour when using python-shell.  If I type in a command that produces some sort of output I get the result immediately on the next line.  If the Python statement I've entered causes an error however, no output is shown.  When I type in the next Python statement and hit enter, the error message  for the previous line will be displayed.

For example when I'm processing some command line arguments:

```
>>> args
Namespace(templatedir=None, xmldir=None)
>>> args.bobbins
>>> args.templatedir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'bobbins'
>>>
```

The first statement prints out the value of the args variable.
The second statement should print out an error message but nothing is printed.
The third statement is correct but actually prints out the error from the second statement.

Does anybody have any idea what's wrong with my Python / Emacs setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Python, and was [fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue21425).